# Ionic iOS build failed (65) on cloud package service

Tags: ios, angularjs, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I've been trying to build my ios app using ionic/angular, and I don't have a mac. I'm using to the ionic cloud to package a release build (ionic package build ios --profile prod --release) but I keep getting this error:

```
Check dependencies
No signing certificate "iOS Distribution" found:  No "iOS Distribution" signing certificate matching team ID "T8HYVJNAPC" with a private key was found.
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'

** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/package/workspace/apps-d02b25ef-15/cordova/platforms/ios/cordova/build-release.xcconfig,-workspace,Monikur.xcworkspace,-scheme,Monikur,-configuration,Release,-destination,generic/platform=iOS,-archivePath,Monikur.xcarchive,archive,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/package/workspace/apps-d02b25ef-15/cordova/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/package/workspace/apps-d02b25ef-15/cordova/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

I've been looking all over deleting plugins that could cause this(like phonegap push), I also reset the icon and splashscreen resources, but no luck.

here are the plugins I have :

```
"cordova-plugin-console": {},
            "cordova-plugin-filepath": {},
            "cordova-plugin-sms": {},
            "cordova-plugin-email": {},
            "cordova-plugin-email-composer": {},
            "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
            "cordova-plugin-compat": {},
            "cordova-plugin-file": {},
            "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "cordova-plugin-clipboard-x": {},
            "cordova-plugin-spinner-dialog": {},
            "cordova-plugin-stripe": {},
            "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
            "ionic-plugin-deeplinks": {
```

along with facebook linkedin and stripe.